# imwrite in OpenCV3.1 doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

When I am trying to save the image using imwrite I get the following error:

```
Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\jalal\AppData\Local\Temp\WER64CE.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\jalal\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7092.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\jalal\AppData\Local\Temp\WER70C2.tmp.mdmp

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Here's my entire code (the code works --imshow shows the blurred image):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//void tintImageBlue(Mat& image);

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    Mat channels[3];

    image = imread("mona1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    split(image, channels);
    //image = 0.2*channels[0] + 0.4*channels[1] + 0.4*channels[2]; //gives us a black and white image (grey)
    image = 0.2126*channels[0] + 0.7152*channels[1] + 0.0722*channels[2]; //wikipedia formula 
    //Colorimetric (luminance-preserving) conversion to grayscale



    if (image.empty())                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    float neighbors[8];
    float neighbors_mean = 0;
    float neighbors_sum;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < 3; iter++){
        for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {


                neighbors[0] = (((i - 1) >= 0 && (j - 1) >= 0) ? image.at<uchar>(i - 1, j - 1) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[1] = (((i - 1) >= 0) ? image.at<uchar>(i - 1, j) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[2] = (((i - 1) >= 0 && (j + 1) < image.cols) ? image.at<uchar>(i - 1, j + 1) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[3] = (((j + 1) < image.cols) ? image.at<uchar>(i, j + 1) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[4] = (((i + 1) < image.rows && (j + 1) < image.cols) ? image.at<uchar>(i + 1, j + 1) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[5] = (((i + 1) < image.rows && (j - 1) >= 0) ? image.at<uchar>(i + 1, j) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[6] = (((i + 1) < image.rows && (j - 1) >= 0) ? image.at<uchar>(i + 1, j - 1) : 0.0f);
                neighbors[7] = (((j - 1) >= 0) ? image.at<uchar>(i, j - 1) : 0.0f);

                neighbors_sum = neighbors[0] + neighbors[1] + neighbors[2] + neighbors[3] +
                    neighbors[4] + neighbors[5] + neighbors[6] + neighbors[7];

                neighbors_mean = neighbors_sum / 8.0f;
                image.at<uchar>(i, j) = neighbors_mean;


                neighbors_sum = 0;
                neighbors_mean = 0;

            }
        }
    }












    //tintImageBlue(image);

    //namedWindow("Grey Mona", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    //imshow("Grey Mona", image);                // Show our image inside it.

    //resizeWindow("Grey Mona",800, 1000);

    //waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    imwrite("10_iteration_blurring.jpg", image);
    return 0;
}
```

But with imwrite it becomes unresponsive. How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `imwrite`? Your nested loops look strange. You're splitting the Mat `image` for each pixel. What are you trying to do in the loops?

Comment: yes, I have tested that separately and works ok.

Comment: Does `imshow` work before `imwrite`? Also try changing file path to another drive and see if it works.

Comment: yes, imshow works separately if I comment imwrite

Comment: I don't have another drive available but my friend who is using similar lab setting and similar drive with same exact opencv property sheet had no problem

Comment: There are many errors in your code. I don't know why its running for you. You're already reading your image as grayscale: `image = imread("mona1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);`. This means the image is a single channel, grayscale image. So the `split` function here: `split(image, channels);` returns `channels` as empty. You check by `if(channels[1].empy()) cout<<"Image is empty"<<endl;`.

Comment: editted the code not still working

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 imwrite("10_iteration_blurring.bmp", image);
```

Comment: So the only change you made was the extension of the output image?  I also think you meant `bmp`, not `bpm`.

Comment: Cool... but I would chalk that up to a temporary fix though.  Not being able to write JPEG to disk seems to be a very glaring issue to me.  Either way, I'm glad to see that you resolved your problem.

Comment: Yeah I do agree with you. I am working on a lab machine which has lots of restrictions and I am not an admin on it. Once I get my own station, I look into this issue further. Thanks!

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Good luck!